# In the PCB design, how should the a2 terminal island of a triac in the 252 sheath be?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, triac, kicad, high-current

For the A2 terminal of the triac in pcb design, I want to use both the front and back surfaces of the pcb. How should the vias be between the back and front surface?(actually zone areas in surfaces)I am using kicad.

Package : TO-252
Max voltage:220Vac
Max Amps:16 A

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you clarify the question please? Click the [edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/590318/edit) link below the question.  Are you asking about clearance between A1, A2, and Gate?  Which size triac (SOIC, TO92, TO220, TO247?)  A part number would help.  What max voltage and current?

Comment: I have uptaded.

Answer (score 1):

> TO-252 package

The [TO-252](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/techdata_basic/ic/package/to252-3_1-e.pdf) series packages are surface-mount technology (SMT) and come in 3, 4, 5 and possibly more pins.

Page 4 of this document describes a typical footprint (literal pin size, not pad size!), where the pins are 1.5 x 2.5mm.  Yours may be different.

For any SMT device, the mating pads should be a little bigger to allow for a proper solder fillet.  So for this device, say 1.8 x 3.0mm.

Given that all pads are larger than the pins, the amount of distance separating them on the printed circuit board (PCB) decreases.  This distance (called "creepage" and "clearance") determines the safe operating voltage.

- **Clearance distance** is the shortest separation *in the air* between two conducting parts.
- **Creepage distance** is the shortest separation *along the surface of an insulating material* between two conducting parts.

Sometimes these are the same (as in the case of PCB traces) but the distinction can be very important.

Ok so the minimum distance between the exposed tracks/pads/pins determines the maximum operating voltage.

The [IPC-2221A Generic Standard on Printed Board Design](http://www-eng.lbl.gov/%7Eshuman/NEXT/CURRENT_DESIGN/TP/MATERIALS/IPC-2221A(L).pdf) section 6.3 Electrical Clearance, is the same table as shown in KiCAD's PCB calculator, Electrical Spacing tab:

[image: IPC-2221 Clearance Creepage Spacing]

For a B2 class board (we're considering minimum distance on exposed pins/pads), 2.5mm is needed for 301-500V. This range was chosen because 240VAC (RMS) has a peak absolute voltage of 339.5V.

So, if the PCB can be designed and assembled with at least 2.5mm distance between A1, A2, and everything else near them, then it will not arc-over.

Note that contaminants on the PCB (such as water and metal dust) can reduce this and cause failure. For that reason, high-voltage tracks such as these are sometimes covered with conformal coating, to prevent such a possibility.

> Max voltage:220Vac Max Amps:16 A

I'm not sure if you can find a TO-252 TRIAC capable of handling 16A. A preliminary check shows most TO-252 TRIACs stop at 8A, likely because these surface-mount components are cooled by the PCB.  And paralleling them is not a good idea, as if one fires just a nanosecond before the other, it will get a surge of current beyond it's rating and likely explode.

For instance, the [LittelFuse QJxx04xx_Series](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Littelfuse%20PDFs/LJ,QJxx04xx_Series.pdf) are good for 8A. I did find a TN1515-600B *SCR* at 15A but anyways.

Your question is about trace ampacity and via ampacity. KiCAD has a trace calculator:

[image: Trace Ampacity]

For 16A, a (single) trace on an external layer, 20mm long, will have to be 13.76mm wide for it to rise 10°C.

Now you *could* use two tracks (I think what you are trying to do), one on top and one on bottom, and almost divide this by two. I'd suggest giving them 10% more though, because the heating of one will slightly heat the other due to proximity. So traces on both sides = 6.88mm, so say 7mm.

As for via ampacity (since you have to get all that current to one side of the PCB), there are many calculators for this on the 'web such as [this one](http://circuitcalculator.com/wordpress/2006/03/12/pcb-via-calculator/).  Using that calculator, one 18mil via could handle 2.56A. Always factor in some safety margin, so say 2A.  Each 18mil via handles 2A, so 16A/2 = 8. Place 8 of these vias between the two tracks near the pin.

Comment: Hello,I have updated my post.(I have added one picture).And,This picture has L1,L2,L3 and L4.Can you tell which category all of these values (L1,L2,L3,L4) belong in the ipc 2221 table for 220Vac=311 Vp?(For example L1--->B2)
let assume standart pcb setting in jlcpcb or pcbway.